# Vue: what is the difference of having a root component vs. just put components in a div root?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I don't understand the difference in approaches of loading up an initial Vue instance.  Right now, I do the following in my app:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
       // component names
    },
    data() {
        return {

        }
    }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
     <div>
           <my-component1></my-component1>
           <my-component2></my-component2>
     </div> 
</div>
```

but then how this way differ?  I know it would load up a `App` within the html `<div id="app"></div>` tag but how does that approach differ?

```
new Vue({
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary benefits of offloading the base component to the `App` component (your 2nd example, with the `render` function) is to clearly separate the processes of app instantiation / entry from the details of the base component.

For smaller projects, or when using the CDN, this might not seem necessary.  But in larger projects with Vue CLI, *main.js* can become lengthy and it becomes increasingly difficult to combine both the app instantiation and the root component into one file.

Without that separation, *main.js* would serve a double purpose of both loading the app and creating a component.

Generally speaking, it's good practice to separate unrelated functionality in projects into separate files for easier maintenance and collaboration, and better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If neither render function nor template option is present, the in-DOM HTML of the mounting DOM element will be extracted as the template. In this case, Runtime + Compiler build of Vue should be used.

---- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#el

Your 1nd example needs a `Compiler` to compile html in runtime.